# How to create correct layout for hexagon field on java swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm creating a field from widgets that are images of hexagons. They look like in this image:

[image: 1]

But I need them like this:

[image: 2]

I think there should be some tricky layout...

```
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,6));
    content.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 700);       

    Cell[][] cells = game.getField().getCells();
    for(Cell[] c: cells){
        for(Cell cell : c){
            content.add(new CellWiget(cell));
        }
    }

    pack();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);`
```

Comment: In the long run, you're probably need to consider making a custom layout manager

Comment: I'd create a drawing JPanel and draw the images in their correct positions.  The Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how.

Comment: What it the purpose of this layout? Is the user expected to interact with it (e.g. if they're buttons). Is it purely visual (no user interaction)? While MadProgrammer might be right in some use-cases, for a purely visual field of hexagons, I'd be tempted to follow the suggestion of @GilbertLeBlanc - and perhaps even if there is *some* interactive element between the hexagons and the user.

Comment: *I think there should be some tricky layout...* - only if you write one or or can find one by searching this site or the web.